# How to add a "Confirm Email" textbox to Stripe's Checkout form?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, stripe-payments

Is it possible to add a "Confirm Email" textbox field to stripe's payment form? I'm using WP Simple Pay (https://wpsimplepay.com/) if that makes any difference. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this. Checkout is entirely controlled by Stripe and you can not change the fields that are in that view.

What you can do is have a first step that collects the customer's email address and have them confirm it explicitly. Once they have, you can then pre-fill the email in Checkout via the `email` parameter for [Custom Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) so that they don't have to enter the value again.

Ultimately though, you're using a third-party plugin so it's likely that you can't control this directly. You might want to reach out to the developers of the plugin to see if it's a future they would implement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply